# ASP.net Page allow execution only on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-control

I have an asp.net page (c#) that I execute daily.

I would like to know if there is a way to allow it to be executed only when its requested by the same ip as the server. Meaning, if another ip runs the page, nothing will happen or it will be redirected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Request.IsLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) to check if the request is local.

Comment: thkx a lot! didn't know about it!

Answer (score 2):

You can query the `IsLocal` property of the `HttpRequest`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Following works also with lower framework than 2.0 (but [HttpRequest.IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) is preferable if available).

C#

```
public static void redirectIfNotServer(string redirectUrl)
{
    // Look for a proxy address first
    var IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    //Trim and lowercase IP if not null
    if ((IP != null)) {
        IP = IP.ToLower().Trim;
    }
    if (IP == null || (IP.Equals("unknown"))) {
        //If IP is null use different detection method, else pull the correct IP from list.
        IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR").ToLower().Trim();
    }

    List<string> IPs = null;
    if (IP.IndexOf(",") > -1) {
        IPs = IP.Split(',').ToList();
    } else {
        IPs = new string[] { IP }.ToList();
    }

    var serverIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR");
    var ipIsServerIp = (from ipAddress in IP swhere ipAddress == serverIP).Any();
    if (!ipIsServerIp) {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Public Shared Sub redirectIfNotServer(ByVal redirectUrl As String)
    ' Look for a proxy address first
    Dim IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
    'Trim and lowercase IP if not null
    If Not IP Is Nothing Then
        IP = IP.ToLower().Trim
    End If
    If IP Is Nothing OrElse (IP.Equals("unknown")) Then
        'If IP is null use different detection method, else pull the correct IP from list.
        IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR").ToLower().Trim
    End If

    Dim IPs As List(Of String)
    If IP.IndexOf(",") > -1 Then
        IPs = IP.Split(","c).ToList
    Else
        IPs = New String() {IP}.ToList
    End If

    Dim serverIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")
    Dim ipIsServerIp = (From ipAddress In IPs Where ipAddress = serverIP).Any
    If Not ipIsServerIp Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

will get you the remote ip, then just compare it to your server ip or "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

Use the [UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) property on the HttpRequest object to get the users address.

Use the [LOCAL_ADDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) variable with the [ServerVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.servervariables.aspx) property to get the servers address from the request object.

Fernando has the better solution by checking the [IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) property.